# How to Get Parent node path for Child node in Inner JSON structure for Java?

Tags: json, parsing, parent

Sample JSON format is like below, need to fetch parent of child node each one step up and at-last have to capture complete path from child node -> top node. Any sample references would be really helpful. Thanks.

**{
"title": "P1-main",
"A": [
{
"title": "P1-A1"
},
{
"title": "P1-B1",
"B": [
{
"title": "P1-2"
}
]
}
]
}**

Example: Get parent path of child node **"P1-2"** like below

**"P1-2"(its parent title) ---> "P1-B1" (its parent title) ---> "P1-main"**

Similarly it could have further "inner" objects also.

Any sample references would be really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Which programming language are you using.